# How to configure buildout to create sphinx documentation using bin/sphinxbuilder

Tags: python, python-sphinx, buildout

In my **buildout.cfg** file i have such code:

```
parts =
    ...
    sphinxbuilder
```

next in same file:

```
eggs=
   ...
   jinja2
   markupsafe
   sphinx
```

and then, at the end of file:

```
[sphinxbuilder]
recipe = collective.recipe.sphinxbuilder
source = ${buildout:directory}/docs-src
build = ${buildout:directory}/docs
```

I do:

```
bin/buildout
```

which gives output (in general: OK):

```
Updating sphinxbuilder.
collective.recipe.sphinxbuilder: writing MAKEFILE..
collective.recipe.sphinxbuilder: writing BATCHFILE..
collective.recipe.sphinxbuilder: writing custom sphinx-builder script..
```

In eggs folder I have `Sphinx` eeg.

After `buildout`, under project directory I have one, new catalog: `docs`.
then I run command:

```
bin/sphinx-quickstart
```

and as `root path for the documentation` I set `docs`

then I edit `docs/conf.py` and uncomment

```
sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath('.'))
```

I run command `bin/sphinxbuilder` and get error:

```
Makefile:12: *** The 'sphinx-build' command was not found. 
Make sure you have Sphinx installed, then set the SPHINXBUILD environment variable to point to the full path of the 'sphinx-build' executable.
Alternatively you can add the directory with the executable to your PATH. If you don't have Sphinx installed, grab it from http://sphinx-doc.org/. Stop.
```

**Main problems**:
(1) How to get sphinx working automaticly with buildout?
(2) How to set right path to project modules (apps) in .rst files? 
(3) Where to put `conf.py` file?

Comment: are you working on Windows? There's a bug in the 0.8.2 py27 collective.recipe.sphinxbuilder egg which causes an error for me (line 146 in the sphinxbuilder/__init__.py) which prevents me from building out. I am still able to use the other scripts, but using "parts=sphinxbuilder" as in their docs does not work correctly

Comment: No, on Linux. Thank You.

Answer (score 1):

On windows here, but I seem to recall a similar issue.

extending the following cfg ensures two things:
1) all entrypoints we generate have access to the sphinx eggs
2) parts which rely on the sphinx entrypoints will be executed -after- those entrypoints are generated

```
[sphinx]
eggs = 
    sphinx
    <if you have theme eggs or other extensions, put em here>

parts =
    sphinx.console_scripts

[sphinx.console_scripts]
recipe = zc.recipe.egg
dependent-scripts = true
eggs = 
    ${sphinx.eggs}
    ${buildout:eggs}
```

Using this, you can also add parts that rely on the build/apidoc executables and your documentation generation becomes part of a one-click buildout:

```
[sphinx.apidoc]
recipe = plone.recipe.command
command = ${buildout:bin-directory}\sphinx-apidoc.exe <all your flags/settiongs based on buildout>
```